# How can I know that the user hit the ESC key in a console with ncurses (Linux)?

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard, console-application, ncurses

I have a problem in detecting whether I just got a plain <kbd>ESC</kbd> key (just code 27) or whether it was another *special* key such as an Arrow Up which sends me three bytes: <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> (27 91 65).

Now, I understand escape sequences, what I don't understand is how can I possibly know that the user actually typed <kbd>ESC</kbd> instead of a special key since both start with 27 and <kbd>ESC</kbd> is only 27?

Note that I use the `wgetch()` function from ncurses as in:

```
// initialization not shown initscr() should be enough for this test
while(!f_should_exit)
{
    int c(wgetch(f_win_input));

    // show codes of what the user types
    //
    printf("got [%d] ", c);
    // prints 27 when I hit ESC
    // prints 27 91 65 when I hit Arrow Up
}
```

I use the <kbd>ESC</kbd> and arrow keys all the time in vim so I would imagine that there is an easy way to specifically detect which key was pressed?!

Comment: BTW, your question is unclear: do you ask how to get `\e` or do you ask how `ncurses` implement that?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I updated my question. The keys I show in my question are the codes I see when I push either the ESC or the Arrow Up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard feature of X/Open Curses.  The manual page for `wgetch` discusses it in [`keypad` mode](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Keypad-mode):

> When a character that could be the beginning of a function key  is  received  (which, on modern terminals, means an **escape** character), curses
>   sets a timer.  If the remainder of the sequence does not come in within
>   the  designated  time,  the character is passed through; otherwise, the
>   function key value is returned.  For this reason, many terminals  experience  a  delay between the time a user presses the escape key and the escape is returned to the program.

By default, `keypad` is not set to true for a given window, i.e., the library does not do this (your program must, if you want function-keys):

```
keypad(win, TRUE);
```

The timeouts are described in ncurses' input-options manual page.  To distinguish an escape character from a function (or cursor, or keypad key), you could use `notimeout`, as mentioned in the discussion of [`nodelay`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay):

> While interpreting an input escape sequence, wgetch(3x)  sets  a  timer
>   while  waiting  for  the  next  character.   If **`notimeout(win, TRUE)`** is
>   called, then wgetch does not set a timer.  *The purpose of  the  timeout
>   is  to differentiate between sequences received from a function key and
>   those typed by a user.*

Comment: Right. Having a timer to do such a thing just sounds silly to me. Maybe I'll implement that later. Thanks for the info, though!

Comment: The library maintains timers, so you needn't make your own.